# np.solve() but when A (first matrix) unknown

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

`np.solve()` works great when you have an equation in the form of `Ax = b`
My problem is that I actually have an equation in the form of `xC = D`, where x is a 2x2 matrix I want to find out, and C and D are 2x2 matrices I'm given.

And because matrix multiplication is generally not commutative, I can't just swap the two around.

Is there an efficient way to solve this in numpy (or other library in python)?

Comment: Consider the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of your equation: Cᵗxᵗ = Dᵗ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x @ C = D` is the same as `D^-1 @ x @ C @ C^-1 = D^-1 @ D @ C^-1` which is `D^-1 @ x = C^-1` which is in the form Ax = b where A is `np.linalg.pinv(D)` and b is `np.linalg.pinv(C)`

which boils down to

```
x = D @ np.linalg.pinv(C)
```

which you could have gotten by just multipying both side of the equation by the inverse of C